# HERE iOS SDK Level 3 Categories

Tags: swift, maps, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

I know that you can search with **level 1** and **level 2 categories** with the **HERE SDK** for **iOS**.

However is it at all possible to search by **level 3 categories**? I've printed out the categories, however the level two categories do not obtain sub categories.

```
        for category in categories! {
            let subs = category.subCategories
            print(category.name)
            print(category.uniqueId)
            for leveltwo in subs {
                print(leveltwo.name)
                print(leveltwo.uniqueId)
                let innersubs = leveltwo.subCategories
                for levelthree in innersubs {
                    print(levelthree.name)
                    print(levelthree.uniqueId)
                }
            }
        }
```

Using the HERE places API, I am able to search places database based on level 3 categories using their ID, for example "**600-6800-0090**". Though with the SDK it seems we cannot use the id.

Answer (score 1):

Just realised that the answer to this is to not use the Premium SDK for HERE and use the iOS Lite SDK. As noted here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-lite/4.3.3.0/dev_guide/topics/search.html#search-for-places you are able to use level 3 categories using the ID.